# Recreating Surface from Curve Network in Geometry Nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, add-on, geometry, procedural

Many CAD programs (for example: Rhino, Moi, FreeCad) have command **Surface from Curve Network**, which create mesh from separate curves, like in bellow images:

[image]

This command work for many shapes, from symmetrical to asymmetrical.

**Is it possible to recreate similar effect in geometry nodes?** Some people with succes recreate loft curves in geometry nodes (for example: [1](https://higgsas-geo-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/curves.html) and [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y0vVycar4lg)), which is similiar command to *Surface from Curve Network*.

For now i was able to achieve result like bellow:

[image]

But it works only for *x* and *y* symmetrical shapes with 2 guide curves and one profile curve. Here is link to blend file with my attempt to recreate *Surface from Curve Network*.

[image]

In short, my attempt is based on scaling loft curves based on X&Y guide curves.

I'm almost sure that there is some solution and i will be very thankfull if someone could help with this topic. If something is unclear please write in comment, i can provide more info or pictures.